# Shell script change shell in between

Tags: python, shell, shebang

I've a shell script with two shebangs, the first one tells #!/bin/sh and after a few lines the other one is #!/usr/bin/env python.

When this script is given executable permission and ran as ./script.sh, the script works fine, uses /bin/sh in first part and uses python interpreter in latter part.

But when the script is run as sh script.sh, the second shebang is not recognized and the script fails. Is there anyway I can force to change the interpreter if the script is run explicitly as sh script.sh.

The reason I need this is because I need to run the scripts through a tool which runs as sh script.sh

Comment: Show your script to get real help.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I actually need to run python , but the tool runs only shell scripts by sh script.sh, so I need to change the interpreter to python

Comment: If you run it as `sh script.sh`, the shebangs are all ignored.  The second one is ignored anyway -- the kernel only looks at the first.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cannot have two `shebang` lines in one script. The `shebang` works only when -

1. it is on the first line
2. it starts in column one

If you need to run python code then have it in another script and then call the script by doing

```
python path/to/the/script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use a shell [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
curdir=`pwd`
/usr/bin/env python <<EOF
import os
print os.listdir("$curdir")
EOF
```

This way, you won't need to distribute the code on two separate files.

As you see, you can even access shell variables from the python code.

Answer (score 0):

have your script.sh script invoke the python interpreter directly:

```
#!/bin/sh
# include full path if needed
python (your python interpreter arguments)
```